# Extract or find categories of skills from Dbpedia or related database

Tags: mediawiki, dbpedia

I am trying to find the categories of a skill. Lets say 'python' as a category 'Programming_language'. Is it possible to find it from dbpedia or related databases. ???? If so, what will be the simple query to do so.

Please help.

Comment: Mediawiki categories can be used in a million ways, can you be a bit more specific? What is it that you are trying to extract, from where?

Comment: @leo - Sorry if I am wrong. I think, DBpedia covers almost all topics. So, finding the category of a word lets say 'Python'  we can get the result as 'programming_language', 'scripting_language'. Is this possible through Dbpedia ?

Comment: In Dbpedia you have `dct:subject`, mostly containing Wikipedia categories. For [Python (programming language)](http://dbpedia.org/page/Python_(programming_language)) with values such as `Dutch_inventions` and `Dynamically_typed_programming_languages`, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @leo exactly. I am new to Sparksql. So, writing a query to find categories is  what i have looked for . But, the problem seems to be in disambiguation . For ex; 'Java' is an Indonesian island as well as 'programming_language'.

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: @leo - Is there a way in dbpedia or related database to find the category of skills ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure I understand. What do you mean by ”category of skills”? Can you give an example of what you are looking for? And maybe provide the query you wrote, and explain how it failed?

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This does not seem like a programming question.

DBpedia data is explorable in many ways, including follow-your-nose from [Python](http://dbpedia.org/page/Python_%28programming_language%29) or [Programming_language](http://dbpedia.org/page/Programming_language).

You may also find faceted exploration helpful, again starting from [Python](http://dbpedia.org/c/9BYH6IQ7).